# Is it possible to run SetTimeout function sequentially?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function which takes multiple functions as parameters and execute these functions sequentially, but each function has `setTimeout` by which make function execution in parallel. Is it possible to make it sequential?

```
  var fun1=function(){
    console.log('Started fun1');
    setTimeout(()=>{console.log('Finished fun1');},2000)
}

var fun2=function(){
    console.log('Started fun2');
    setTimeout(()=>{console.log('Finished fun2');},2000)
}


function fun3(arr){
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    arr[i]();
}

fun3([fun1,fun2]);
```

Comment: In what order do you want them to run? - in either case, the talk [THE EVENT LOOP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IsjjMRyIF8) may help you

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you're trying to do? Do you have control of the the `funX` functions? If so, can you call the next `funX` function inside a `funX` function? If that won't work, can you remove the `setTimeout` from each `funX` and have the caller function call `setTimeout` on `funX`?

Answer (score 4):

Your functions are asynchronous and asynchronous functions need some way of indicating when they are finished. Typically this is done with a callback or promise. Without that there is no way to know when they are finished. If they returned a promise, you might do something like this:

```js
var fun1 = function() {
  console.log('Started fun1');
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Finished fun1');
      resolve(true)
    }, 2000)
  })

}

var fun2 = function() {
  console.log('Started fun2');
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Finished fun2');
      resolve(true)
    }, 2000)
  })
}


function fun3(arr) {
  let p = Promise.resolve()
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    p = p.then(arr[i]);
  }
  return p
}

fun3([fun1, fun2]);
```

You can write the loop a little more succinctly with `reduce()`:

```
function fun3(arr){
  return arr.reduce((a, c) => a.then(c), Promise.resolve())
}
```

If you can use `async/await` the last function would be a little easier to read. Since the `async` function returns a promise you can also easily know when the whole thing is done:

```
async function fun3(arr){
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    await arr[i]();
}


fun3([fun1,fun2])
.then(() => console.log("finished"))
```

Of course if it's possible to just have simple functions that are not asynchronous, a lot of these problems go away…you could just run then in a timer outside the functions.

Answer (score 0):

**You can add the next function *inside* the `setTimeout` callback.**

For example,

```js
var fun1=function(){
    console.log('Started fun1');
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log('Finished fun1');
        fun2(); // Start the next timeout.
    },2000)
}

var fun2=function(){
    console.log('Started fun2');
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log('Finished fun2');
    },2000)
}

// This should output 'Started fun1', delay, 
// output 'Finished fun1' and then 'Started fun2',
// delay, and then finally output 'Finished fun2'.
fun1();
```